# How to manually invoke CREATE TABLE when using Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, database-migration, create-table, android-room

Given this custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` in Java:

```
public class ExamplesOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "app.db";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT =
            "CREATE TABLE examples (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT);";

    public ExamplesOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS examples");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I can reference the `CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT` in an database migration aka. `onUpgrade()` without duplicating the SQL code.

I would like to implement the same with [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) and [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) as shown here:

```
@Database(
        entities = [
            (Example::class)
        ],
        version = 2
)
abstract class ExamplesDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {

        const val NAME = "examples"

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ExamplesDatabase? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): ExamplesDatabase =
                INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
                        INSTANCE = it
                    }
                }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
                Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ExamplesDatabase::class.java,
                        NAME)
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build()

        private val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                // How to invoke CREATE TABLE here?
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This time the actual table definition is infered from the `Example` model. How can I infer the `CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT` from Room so I can use it in an migration? I want to avoid writing the statement **manually** and thereby defining it **twice**: once in the model, one in the SQL statement.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a way to avoid the implicit duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You can find create table SQL from class "ExamplesDatabase_Impl.java", there is no CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT define, only hard code.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is a way to do that. See the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html).

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Fruit` (`id` INTEGER, "
                + "`name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    }
};
```

It seems that you have to write it yourself.

Comment: That implicitely duplicates the table definition. Once the `@Entity` model defines it. Once the SQL statement defines it. I don't want to maintain that.

Comment: Yeaa, that kind of sucks... Haven't found another way still so thanks Joshua !